# Are real time cross-platform applications between html and android possible

Tags: unity-game-engine, cross-platform

I'm currently investigating the scope of my project and have come across an issue with regards to the platform on which it can operate. The initial goal is to create a cross platform game across html, andriod and ios.

Is this type of application possible? It is important to note that it would require real time(low latency and consistent) interaction between the three platforms.

If so what are some tools I should take advantage of while developing.

Comment: Sure, Websockets as a communication layer (relatively easy to work with) essentially the only actual latency is the network latency if properly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing this exact sort of thing using the 3rd party asset within the Unity UI's:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#/content/10872

and custom Socket.IO (http://socket.io/) server implementation.  Works like a champ and is totally agnostic wether the client is Unity3D or just a browser.